# MLP to initialize LSTM cell state in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Can we use output of MLP as cell state in LSTM network and train the MLP too with back propagation?

This is similar to image captioning with CNN & LSTM where the output of CNN is flattened and used as initial hidden/cell state and train the stacked network where even the CNN part is updated through back-propagation.

I tried an architecture in keras to achieve the same. Please find the code [here](https://github.com/Vivek-B/Kaggle/blob/master/mlp_lstm_mnist_demo.ipynb).

But the weights of the MLP are not being updated. I understand this is more straightforward in tensorflow where we can explicitly mention which parameters to update with the loss, but can anyone help me with keras API?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, we can. Simply pass the output as [`the initial hidden state`](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/#lstm). Remember that an LSTM has two hidden states, `h` and `c`. You can read more about this [here](http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/). Note that you also do not have to create multiple keras models, but can simple connect all the layers.:

```
# define mlp 
mlp_inp = Input(batch_shape=(batch_size, hidden_state_dim))
mlp_dense = Dense(hidden_state_dim, activation='relu')(mlp_inp)

## Define LSTM model
lstm_inp = Input(batch_shape=(batch_size, seq_len, inp_size))
lstm_layer = LSTM(lstm_dim)(lstm_inp, initial_state=[mlp_dense,mlp_dense])
lstm_out = Dense(10,activation='softmax')(lstm_layer)

model = Model([mlp_inp, lstm_inp], lstm_out)
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=  ['accuracy'])
```

However, because of the above fact about having two states, you may want to consider two MLP layers for each initial state separately.

```
# define mlp 
mlp_inp = Input(batch_shape=(batch_size, hidden_state_dim))
mlp_dense_h = Dense(hidden_state_dim, activation='relu')(mlp_inp)
mlp_dense_c = Dense(hidden_state_dim, activation='relu')(mlp_inp)

## Define LSTM model
lstm_inp = Input(batch_shape=(batch_size, seq_len, inp_size))
lstm_layer = LSTM(lstm_dim)(lstm_inp, initial_state=[mlp_dense_h,mlp_dense_c])
lstm_out = Dense(10,activation='softmax')(lstm_layer)

model = Model([mlp_inp, lstm_inp], lstm_out)
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=  ['accuracy'])
```

Also, note that when you go about saving this model, use [`save_weights`](https://keras.io/models/about-keras-models/) instead of [`save`](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model) because `save_model` can not handle the initial state passing. Also, as a slight note.